# Facebook Account Kit: Unable to exchange authorization code for access Token

Tags: node.js, facebook

I have integrated the facebook AccountKit to authenticate a user based on SMS Verfication:

I am using the Authorization Code Flow to authenticate a user. I successfully receive the Auth Code. As required I send this auth Code to my server. The server makes a Graph API Request to exchange this auth code with an access Token. It makes the following Request:

```
GET https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.2/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code<authorization_code>&access_token=AA|<facebook_app_id>|<app_secret>
```

In response all I get is the following:

> '{"error":{"message":"Service temporarily
>   unavailable","type":"EMApiException","is_transient":true,"code":
>   2,"fbtrace_id":"DOlg5YLDse5"}}'

Other Details:
My Client Is an Android Application.
My Server uses Node.js

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: No. I had been using the wrong app secret